# How to save data into BLOB variable in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, binary, byte, blob

I have this table (bytestest) in my DB:
 
|NAME | TYPE 
| id      | int 
| varbin  | varbinary(8000) 
| varblob | blob 
And I want to add data, read from a file, into the varblob column.
I write this snippet of code using python3.

```
cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
f = open('data.txt', 'rb')
line = f.readline()
sql = "INSERT INTO bytestest(varblob) VALUES (%s)"
cur.execute(sql, (line))
mysql.connection.commit()
cur.close()
```

But it returns an error: `not all arguments converted during bytes formatting`.
the file data.txt contains AAAA and if I print(line) it returns `b'AAAA'`.
How can I store the data?
To store data into varbin (varbinary column) do I have to follow the same method?

Comment: *the file data.txt contains AAAA* Is this textual value (4 bytes) or hexadecimal value (2 bytes)?

Comment: Hexadecimal literal for `'AAAA'` text looks like `x'41414141'` or `0x41414141` (pay attention - `%s` will make them `'x\'41414141\''` and `'0x41414141'` which is wrong).

Comment: Sorry but I didn't get. A in hexadecimal value is 0x41 so if I write AAAA or \x41\x41\x41\x41 they both take 4 bytes? am I wrong?

Comment: Maybe it is correct in python. But this value is not legal in MySQL. Your final query text must be `INSERT INTO bytestest(varblob) VALUES (0x41414141)` or `INSERT INTO bytestest(varblob) VALUES (x'41414141')`

Comment: @Akina So what I need to do to store them into a blob variable? use %b format?

Comment: Study this: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/hexadecimal-literals.html

Comment: From the other side - if the value `'AAAA'` read from the file must be stored as 4-byte string then save it as-is, as text. The only difference between BLOB and TEXT datatypes is in default collation which is BINARY for BLOB column.

Comment: @Akina `INSERT INTO bytestest(varblob) VALUES (0x41414141)` that is fine but in this way I must hardcode the values to insert and I can't for example take them from an external input. Anyway thank you for the last answer but i'm working on binary data in MySQL for a research purpose so I'm not instrested in store them like a TEXT

Comment: I solved in this way: `cur.execute("INSERT INTO bytesTest(varblob) VALUES (X'" + byteStringVal + "');")` where byteStringVal is somthing like 41414141

Comment: Immediate concatenation is a way to injection. Test `sql = "INSERT INTO bytestest(varblob) VALUES (X%s)"`providing `'41414141'` in `line`.